# Sql query to find replacement items

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not the greatest with sql but I am struggling with writing this query.  The situation is I have an item table.  If the item is obsolete 'obso' and has a replacement ID then in a query I should select that replacement item rather than the already obsoleted one.  Here is what i have and a few pics to make it clearer.

```
select 
o.ReplacementItemID,
o.ItemStatus,
o.Description,
o.ItemWarrantyID,
o.Id as OriginalItemId
from
(
    select 
        id,
        ItemStatus,
        Description,
        ItemWarrantyID,
        ReplacementItemID
    from item
    where ItemStatus = 'obso'   
)o
inner join Item i
on o.ReplacementItemID = i.Id
```

Which gives me [image]

which is incorrect the warranty id should be 110 like the two examples below:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you should be selecting `i.ItemWarrantyID` instead.

Comment: because for item id 948032 ReplacementItemId is null.

Comment: @JaydipJ That is not the issue.  The original item is 834852.  The replacement is 948032 (which you can see in the ReplacementItemID for the 834852).  You can also see the OriginalItemId in the first picture.  The issue has to do with the ItemWarrantyID as both Troy Bryant and sgeddes mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sgeddes mentioned in the comments you are referencing the wrong ItemWarrantyID.  Your...

```
from
(
select 
    id,
    ItemStatus,
    Description,
    ItemWarrantyID,
    ReplacementItemID
from item
where ItemStatus = 'obso'   
)o
```

Is all about the original.  The part after that...

```
inner join Item i
on o.ReplacementItemID = i.Id
```

Makes it so you can only see parts who have a replacement.  The issue is you only utilize the original while filtering out all of the rows that don't have a replacement.

So your...

```
select 
o.ReplacementItemID,
o.ItemStatus,
o.Description,
o.ItemWarrantyID,
o.Id as OriginalItemId
```

Should be...

```
select 
o.ReplacementItemID,
o.ItemStatus,
o.Description,
i.ItemWarrantyID,
o.Id as OriginalItemId
```

Assuming you are only looking for originals (which it seems like you are based off of the `where ItemStatus = 'obso'` and your `inner join` and many other things)